# Map Many to Many relationship without navigation property

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Is is possible to map a many to many relationship without having a navigation property on one of the ends? For example I have some widgets and some users who can star particular widgets. I'd like to be able to see what widgets a user cares stars, but I don't really care about seeing all the users who have starred a particular widget

Widget.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

User.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public ICollection<Widget> StarredWidgets { get; set; }
```

With this setup, EF will generate a one-to-many relationship from Widgets to Users. However, it needs to be a many to many. I realize I could add a `public ICollection<User> Users` to `Widget.cs`, but just seeing if there was another way around this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can and this case *must* define the many-to-many relationship with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.StarredWidgets)
    .WithMany() // <- no parameter here because there is no navigation property
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        m.MapRightKey("WidgetId");
        m.ToTable("UserWidgets");
    });
```

Comment: This seems to setup the database tables correctly and when I call `myUserPrefObj.StarredWidgets.Add(myWidget)` the entry gets added to the join table correctly. However, later when I try to reload `myUserPrefObj` using a different db context, the `StarredWidgets` property is null. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind. I realized I forgot to mark the navigation property `virtual`.

Comment: @Kyle: That's "normal" :) If you want to load an entity and *include* one of its navigation property you must use, well... *Include*: `context.Users.Include(u => u.StarredWidgets).Where...`. Or mark `StarredWidgets` as `virtual`, then lazy loading will load the collection, but it will require a second DB query. With `Include` you need only one query.

Comment: The .Map() part may be omitted.