# Entity Framework 6 One-To-Many Relationship without Navigation Property

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have 2 table: A and B with one-to-many relationship, these table were implemented in EF 6 as below:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int AID {get;set;}
    public string AName {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int BID {get;set;}
    public string BName {get;set;}
    public int AID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("AID")]
    public A InstanceOfClassA {get;set;}
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I retrieve `B` from context, `InstanceOfClassA` always null.

**Assumption**

Because there's no navigation property refer to `B` in `A` entity, therefore, entity framework doesn't lazy load `A` when retrieve `B`.

**Expecting**

Because I don't need to access `B` from `A`, therefore I want to get rid of navigation property in `A` but still preserve the ability of lazy load `A` from `B`.

**NOTE**

I saw a post from [Map Many to Many relationship without navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718699/map-many-to-many-relationship-without-navigation-property) but this doesn't suit in my case.

Is there anyway that I can force to lazy load `A` from `B` without using explicit include `var b = context.B.Include(x => x.InstanceOfClassA);`? Maybe Custom Convention

**EDIT 1**

I tried using convention as follow and still get no luck:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<B>()
    .HasRequired<A>(x => x.InstanceOfClassA);
```

Comment: If you're going down vote my question, please take some time to leave a comment on what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question. I spent a bit of time researching the same thing so that I wouldn't have to Include() on everything I was sending from a Service. I think I ended up creating a constructor in a partial class that loaded nav properties. Dunno if that works for you.

Comment: I though about manually loaded dependency too. But still looking for a solution that can be re used in future project. Custom Convention for example, but I go no idea on how to implement custom convention for this kind of relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get lazy loading working, you have to mark navigation property with `virtual` keyword:

```
[ForeignKey("AID")]
public virtual A InstanceOfClassA {get;set;}
```

Comment: Work like a charm! I was mixing up eager loading and lazy loading

Comment: Is this specifically just for the difference between lazy loading and eager? `virtual` seems necessary to get it to work at all