# Entity Framework - Inserting model with many to many mapping

Tags: entity-framework

How can I insert a model `Tag` that belongs to a model `Post` when I have the models setup like this:

**Post**

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public Post()
    {
       Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}
```

**Tag**

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This question suggests to create a Post object then add Tags to the Tags collection, I couldn't get it working:
[Insert/Update Many to Many Entity Framework . How do I do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253165/insert-update-many-to-many-entity-framework-how-do-i-do-it)

I want to add Tag to Post already in the database, how can I do that with EF. I'm new to EF.

This is what I've tried, if I send this to the API it doesn't insert any records and I can see that the new `tag Id = 0` which doesn't exist in the database, but I'd think that'd cause a foreign key constraint error, not sure If I need to do something to auto generate Id for the tag:

```
{
    Name: "test"
}
```

API

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Tag))]
public IHttpActionResult PostTag(Tag tag)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var post = new Post();
    var tags = new List<Tag>();
    tags.Add(tag);

    post.Tags.Add(tag);
    post.Id = 10;
    db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tag.Id }, tag);
}
```

Comment: *How can I insert a Tag with a PostId?* Tag doesn't have a `PostId`, but what you mean is: how can I store connections between Posts and Tags? That's as simple as adding existing tags (i.e. attached as `Unchanged`) to Post.Tags.

Comment: Your original question had the correct mapping, you shouldn't have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you said there is `Many-To-Many` relation which the `PostTag` is connection table between `Tag` and `Post` then your models don't show any `many-to-many` relation, so from what I have seen there is 
`one-to-many` between `Post` and `Tag` because of your model definition.

if you want to make `many-to-many` relation between them you have to something like below:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public Tag()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
} 
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
    public Post()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}
```

and in `OnModelCreating` make relation by fluent api as below :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
        .HasMany(s => s.Posts)
        .WithMany(c => c.Tags)
        .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("TagId");//TagId
            cs.MapRightKey("PostId");//PostId
            cs.ToTable("PostTag");
        });
}
```

or vice versa

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Tags)
    .WithMany(c => c.Posts)
    .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("PostId");//PostId
            cs.MapRightKey("TagId");//TagId
            cs.ToTable("PostTag");
        });
```

as you can see and know there should be a table named `PostTag` in database which have two columns as keys which have a script like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostTag](
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PostId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PostTag] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TagId] ASC,
    [PostId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostTag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTag_Post] FOREIGN KEY([PostId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Post] ([Id])
GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostTag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTag_Post]
GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostTag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTag_Tag] FOREIGN KEY([TagId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tag] ([TagId])
GO 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostTag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTag_Tag]
GO
```

take a look at [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for more info.

UPDATE:

if you want establish `zero-to-many` relation between `Post` and `Tag` then the models should be like below:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public Post()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
}
```

and one to many relation with fluent api :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
   .HasMany(o1 => o1.Tags);
```

as your comment you don't want `Tag` have navigate property so you should define a property as `Nullable` in `Tag` which is feign key, if there is a relation between them you should establish relation at least by navigate property or `Nullable` property.

**The correct answer** came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977359/adding-a-model-with-join-to-another-model-for-many-to-many-without-navigation-pr/53978180?noredirect=1#comment94795986_53978180) (with no change):
You want to assign a tag to exist post you should find that Post firstly then add a tag to it, if that tag does exist in DB a relation will be made between Tag and found Post if that Tag does not exist then Tag will be inserted to DB,

Take a look at this :

```
var post = context.Posts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 4);//That Id would be you specific Post Id
var existTag = context.Tags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1); //Exist Tag in DB
post.Tags.Add(existTag);
context.SaveChanges();
//Inserting new tag to DB and assign it to Post also
Tag newTag = new Tag // Does not exist in DataBase
{
    Name = "tag2"
};
post.Tags.Add(newTag);// By this tag2 will be insert into Tag table first and then added to post (insert new record to PostTag)
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I don't want a navigation property on the Tag model though, I don't want all the posts available for each tag

Comment: You don't want navigate property as Post in Tag model ? you also don't want posts available for each tag ?, so you want `one-to-many` relation from `Post` to `Tag` which mean each post have many tags or what ?

Comment: What you suggested is every Post for each tag. I want to know how to do the insert for the relation I've setup, there's no problem with setting up the many to many I've checked the database and the modelBuilder has created the PostTag table. My question is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253165/insert-update-many-to-many-entity-framework-how-do-i-do-it, I can't get the insert part working

Comment: Also I used this question to setup the m to m relationship without a navigation property on the Tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718699/map-many-to-many-relationship-without-navigation-property

Comment: I open a new question thats easier to read I can't close this one though

Comment: @matt, what is the insert code, please provide insert code and the error you faced with.

Comment: There is no need to ask question twice just edit this.